# I started getting below error for all provider hosted apps in SharePoint while app tries to communicate with SharePoint to fetch any data

Tags: sharepoint-2013

App token requested from appredirect.aspx for site: b765c3df-7595-40c2-b046-d963cdd24c69 but there was an error in generating it.  This may be a case when we do not need a token or when the app principal was not properly set up.  LaunchUrl:https://upstreamapps-tst.bpglobal.com/P2P/Pages/Home.aspx?SPHostUrl=https://upstream-tst.bpglobal.com/sites/P2P&SPHostTitle=Home&SPAppWebUrl=https://app-ffd4815eb3dcad.bpglobal.com/sites/P2P/BPP2PToolApp&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=1&SPProductNumber=15.0.4763.1000&pageView=1&SenderId=5473DE490 Exception Message:The app i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|afa504e0-9a51-4408-aaf5-52eae8ab82c4@48647fce-23e7-4953-8d70-f38e98897765 does not have an endpoint or its endpoint is not valid.  Stacktrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppRedirectPage.ValidateAndProcessRequest().  Since this is a nonfatal error, it will be sanitized and posted to the app as part of the app launch.